# Splice method don't properly

Tags: javascript, splice

My splice method don't work here (don't give my code attention just I want to know why this code don't work in my console).

```js
function capSpace(txt) {
  // write your code here
  wordSplit = txt.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < wordSplit.length; i++) {
    if (wordSplit[i].toUpperCase() == wordSplit[i]) {
      wordSplit.splice(5, 0, " ")
    }

  }
  return wordSplit
}

console.log(capSpace("fausJkalMalkihkLhb"));
```

Comment: What does "Work" mean? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You keep adding to the array, so it never reaches the end.

Comment: Why do you always splice at index `5`?

Comment: Try printing `wordsplit` each time through the loop and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to increment the `i` for each character that you add to the array.

I assume you're trying to add a space before each capital letter, in which case you need to add it at the `i` index, not the 5th index.

```js
function capSpace(txt) {
  // write your code here
  wordSplit = txt.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < wordSplit.length; i++) {
    if (wordSplit[i].toUpperCase() == wordSplit[i]) {
      wordSplit.splice(i, 0, " ");
      i++;
    }

  }
  return wordSplit
}

var result = capSpace("fausJkalMalkihkLhb").join('');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The splice method is adding an empty space to the `wordSplit` array in your snippet found here:

```
wordSplit.splice(5, 0, " ")
```

This is incrementing the length of `wordSplit` on each iteration and the condition of the for loop:

```
i < wordSplit.length
```

will never be satisfied because the length of `wordSplit` increases which creates an infinite loop and therefore is never able to return `wordSplit` and therefore never able to console.log the variable of `result` because it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thank you so much

Comment: @Faisal I'm glad I was able to understand and answer your specific question.